# VW Beetle Distributor Identification/Timing Specs

Tags: vw, beetle, distributor

Can anyone tell me what kind of distributor this is? I'm specifically trying to find out what the timing specs are. I was told it is electronic. I had a mechanic a while back tell me it needed to have significantly more advance than the "normal" kind. I currently suspect the shop set the timing for this one to the timing for that on typical air cooled bugs. (mine's a 1968).[image]

Comment: I like the pic.  Super clean and tidy.  Very nice.

Comment: Thanks, even though I can't take much credit for it :)

Answer (score 1):

My father has a '73 thing and has gone back and forth between electronic and points.

It APPEARS to be electronic.  It looks like there is a black box on the back of the dist with a black and red wire coming out.  The basic way to tell is to pop of the dist cap, remove the rotor, remove the disc.  Underneath you will either see the electronic pickup or points.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a more informed answer, and after buying my own timing light and fixing what the shop did (timing bolt was completely loose so timing was whatever it wanted to be that day): It is electronic. I ended up setting the timing to 36 degrees before top dead center (BTDC) at high RPMs. It makes for a nice, smooth, quite run on the highway at 65 mph. It does run more cold-blooded around town and takes a while to warm up at this setting. But it's sure worth it when commuting.

This link was, among the many out there, about the only one that ended up being helpful:

http://www.volksworld.com/tech-guides/vw-diy-guides/setting-ignition-timing-with-a-strobe-3584